# Xcode 12 : Running code on device very slow

Tags: xcode, ios14, xcode12

Code running on xcode 12 is very slow. always stuck at launch screen for 5 to 10 mins
also followed the link but thats not helped much.

Going to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/ and removing contents of "iOS DeviceSupport" and removed the contents of "iOS Device Logs and "Derived data" too

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651012?login=true#reply-to-this-question

Answer (score 5):

These two steps solved the issue for me:

A. delete the iOS DeviceSupport ( ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport)

B. Change Scheme

```
 1. In the XCode menu, Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

 2. Open the Info tab.

 3. Uncheck the Debug executables checkbox.
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue after removing content of  "iOS DeviceSupport" everything back to normal